# Nodes in the most inner core of K-shell in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I want to obtain nodes in the most inner core of the k-shell algorithm corresponding to the highest degree using NetworkX in Python. I tried to get the nodes using the following code but I encountered the error "AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'keys'"

```py
# Create a digraph
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=673)  
G.add_edge(2,4,weight=201)  
G.add_edge(4,1,weight=20)  
G.add_edge(2,3,weight=96)  
G.add_edge(3,4,weight=44)  
G.add_edge(6,3,weight=7)  
G.add_edge(6,4,weight=96)  
G.add_edge(5,6,weight=10)  
G.add_edge(7,6,weight=10)  
G.add_edge(8,6,weight=10)  

# Calculate k-shells
shells = nx.algorithms.core.k_shell(g)

# Find the maximum k-shell value
max_k_shell = max(k_shells.keys())

# Get the nodes in the most inner core
inner_core_nodes = k_shells[max_k_shell]

# Print the nodes in the most inner core
print(inner_core_nodes)
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`k_shell`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.core.k_shell.html) returns a subgraph.

If you don't provide a value for `k`, then the outer shell is returned (which corresponds to the nodes of highest degree), you can also use [`k_core`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.core.k_core.html#networkx.algorithms.core.k_core) (those two are equivalent for `k=None` since there is no nodes of higher degree):

```
H = nx.k_shell(G)
# or 
H = nx.k_core(G)

H.nodes
# NodeView((1, 2, 4, 3, 6))
```

Note that you could also use [`core_number`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.core.core_number.html#networkx.algorithms.core.core_number) to get the core numbers and manually filter those:

```
d = nx.core_number(G)
max_degree = max(d.values())

nodes = {k for k, v in d.items() if v == max_degree}
```

Output: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code - you've named the variable 'shells', but you're trying to access it using 'k_shells'.

Change your code to this:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create a digraph
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=673)
G.add_edge(2, 4, weight=201)
G.add_edge(4, 1, weight=20)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=96)
G.add_edge(3, 4, weight=44)
G.add_edge(6, 3, weight=7)
G.add_edge(6, 4, weight=96)
G.add_edge(5, 6, weight=10)
G.add_edge(7, 6, weight=10)
G.add_edge(8, 6, weight=10)

# Calculate k-shells
k_shells = nx.algorithms.core.k_shell(G)

# Find the maximum k-shell value
max_k_shell = max(k_shells)

# Get the nodes in the most inner core
inner_core_nodes = k_shells[max_k_shell]

# Print the nodes in the most inner core
print(inner_core_nodes)
```

Comment: Thanks, though I still get the error: AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'keys' on Networkx 3.1.

Comment: Updated my code. Test it again, please!